Trying to fetch data from backend to frontend
I am trying to get data from backend(MongoDB) from react app called an api and handled the toute in backend as well and returned the response
But I am getting 404 not found response
Well I've tries in Postman to ckeck whether my backend api is able to fetch data from db It is working perfectly fine and the api returning the expected data, But in react app I am facing issue
Any suggestions...Thank you in advance
//App.js:
useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchJobs() {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get('/api/jobs');
          setJobs(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching jobs:', error);
        }
      }
      fetchJobs();
    }, []);

//index.js(in backend)
const jobRoutes = require('./routes/jobRoutes');
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/joblistingDB",{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => {
    console.log("connected to db")
    app.listen(PORT,()=>{
        console.log("listening");
    })
})
.catch((err)=> console.log(err))

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use('/api', jobRoutes);

//jobRoutes.js(backend)
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const jobController = require('../Controllers/jobController');
const Job = require('../models/job');

// Define routes for job listings
// router.get('/jobs', jobController.getAllJobs);

Route to get all jobs
router.get('/jobs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const jobs = await Job.find();
      console.log("Fetched in backend successfully");
      res.json(jobs);
    } catch (error) {   
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  });


I don't see any exports from jobRoutes.js.

I think the problem is with how you make your requests, I'm not sure if you are using proxy, but I'm assuming not.
you should send the request as follows:
await axios.get(`${your_backend_domain}/route`);

the reasone why it return 404 is probably because you are requesting from the frontend and not the backend.
or you can create a new axios cleint and set the base domain to your backend domain and use it instead of using axios directly
this is how you do it:
const apiClient = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'your backend url'
})

